# node - stylus not rendering properly

Tags: stylus

I am new to stylus, And I decide to try this. In which I created a folder called "stylus" on my "D" drive and installed stylus in that folder. now I got a folder called "node_modules" inside 'stylus' folder created.

Again I created new folder as "css" under the "stylus" folder(main folder) sibling to "node_modules". in the css folder I have a file called "main.styl".

I added some of property in that file like:

```
font-size = 14px

body
   font font-size Arial, sans-serif
```

and I run the command like this:

```
D:\stylus\css>stylus -c main.styl
```

It should suppose to create a 'main.css' file within 'css' folder. But I am getting error like this:

```
D:\stylus\css>stylus -c main.styl
'stylus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the issue here. what else I need to do further this to work? any one help me please.

In my system, JS is disabled for this site. please excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install stylus globally on your system with the -g flag option :

```
npm install stylus -g
```